# How to connect Saxon XSLT to Oracle database on Amazon AWS RDS service

Tags: oracle, saxon

I wish to run an XSLT transform (Engine == Saxon EET v9-8-0-12J) on a windows platform and connect to an RDS Oracle database via SSL.

Why? How do I make a connection?

### What should work

The following transform worked in 2019, but does not work in 2020.

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="3.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:sql="http://saxon.sf.net/sql"
    xmlns:java="http://saxon.sf.net/java-type"
    xmlns:xyz="<redacted>"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs java xyz"
    extension-element-prefixes="sql">

<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:param name="db" />
<xsl:param name="username" />
<xsl:param name="password" />

<xsl:variable name="connections">
  <tns-entries>
    <tns-entry name="EXP">  
      (DESCRIPTION =
        (ADDRESS_LIST =
          (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCPS)(HOST = <redacted>)(PORT = <redacted>))
        )
        (CONNECT_DATA =
          (SID = <redacted>)
        )
       (SECURITY = (SSL_SERVER_CERT_DN = "C=US,ST=Washington,L=Seattle,O=Amazon.com,OU=RDS,CN=<redacted>"))
      )
    </tns-entry>
  </tns-entries>
  <queries>
    <query db="EXP" schema="<redacted>" cols="sysdate" view="dual" where="1=1" />
  </queries>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="jdbConnectionString"
  select="concat('jdbc:oracle:thin:@', translate( normalize-space( $connections/tns-entries/tns-entry[@name=$db]/text()), ' ', ''))"/>

<xsl:variable name="schema" select="$connections/queries/query[@db=$db]/@schema" />
<xsl:variable name="cols"   select="$connections/queries/query[@db=$db]/@cols" />
<xsl:variable name="view"   select="$connections/queries/query[@db=$db]/@view" />
<xsl:variable name="where"  select="$connections/queries/query[@db=$db]/@where" />

<xsl:variable name="connection" as="java:java.sql.Connection">
  <sql:connect driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
               database="{$jdbConnectionString}" user="{$username}" password="{$password}"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:function name="xyz:sql" as="element(row)*">
  <xsl:param name="columns" as="xs:string" />
  <xsl:param name="view"    as="xs:string" />
  <xsl:param name="where-clause" as="xs:string" />
  <sql:query
      connection="$connection"
      column="{$columns}"
      table="{string-join( tokenize( $view, ',') ! concat( $schema, '.', normalize-space(.)), ',')}"
      where="{$where-clause}"
      row-tag="row"
      column-tag="#auto" />
</xsl:function>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <result>
    <db name="{$db}"><xsl:value-of select="$jdbConnectionString" /></db>
    <dataset><xsl:copy-of select="xyz:sql($cols,$view,$where)" /></dataset>
  </result>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When executed in 2020 against an RDS database, the following error is returned ...

```
java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
```

This database can be connected to without problem, outside of Saxon XSLT (with programs like sqlplus.exe etc.)
The above transform also works for on-prem databases.

### What has changed

Some global option settings for Oracle are stored in a file called sqlnet.ora. Normally Oracle clients take notice of this file, however I suspect that the java layer that Saxon XSLT leverages does not respect this file. I may have made some changes to this file, and this is the only environmental factor that I can think of that has changed.

Could this be the issue?

### sqlnet.ora file contents

```
# SQLNET.ORA 
# Version 1.2 9/2/2007
names.directory_path = (TNSNAMES)
names.default_domain = world
name.default_zone = world
WALLET_LOCATION = (SOURCE = (METHOD = FILE) (METHOD_DATA = (DIRECTORY = <redacted>)))
SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION = FALSE
SSL_VERSION = 1.2
SSL_CIPHER_SUITES = (<redacted>)
SSL_SERVER_DN_MATCH = OFF
```

I cannot turn SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION on, nor SSL_SERVER_DN_MATCH on due to corporate security policy.  :-(

Any advise or helpful hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking just yesterday at the sql:connection code in Saxon, which I'm afraid has become rather out of date; these days JDBC recommends that connections are made using a named `DataSource` registered using JNDI, but Saxon is still using the old approach using database name plus name of JDBC driver class.

If you're able to write Java code that successfully creates a JDBC connection, then I suggest you wrap that code as an extension function, and use it in place of the Saxon `sql:connection` call. (And ideally, if you get it working, please share it!)

I'm afraid the Saxon SQL extension is something of a second-class citizen. It was mainly contributed piecemeal by users who only needed to solve simple problems and so it's a bit of a patchwork in terms of coverage; in addition we've never had the kind of test suite that's really needed, showing connections to a dozen different database products on different platforms. Nor do we (at Saxonica) understand those database products well enough to offer users much help with database-specific problems. But once you can get a connection, it usually works fine.